# Blank canvas HTML, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

why I'm getting blank canvas?
When e.target.result is changed to normal url of an image somewhere from web (in img.src = e.target.result) it's working perfectly fine. Adding img tag with src=e.target.result works also.

```
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
        continue;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {
          var span = document.createElement('span');
          span.innerHTML = ['<canvas class="thumb" title="', escape(theFile.name), '" id="', escape(theFile.name), '"></canvas>'].join('');
          document.getElementById('photo-list').insertBefore(span, null);
          var ctx=document.getElementById(escape(theFile.name)).getContext("2d");
          var img=document.createElement('img');
          img.src = e.target.result;
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        };
      })(f);
      reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point in your code where you execute

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

The image hasn't finished loading (it's client side but loading still takes a bit of time).  So wrap that drawImage call in a load handler for the `<img>` element, like:

```
img.onload = (function (ctx) {
  return function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
  };
})(ctx);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b9fodfu4/)

Comment: the inner return fn. Unnecessary

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan There are multiple ctx's

Comment: Maybe @RokoC.Buljan has a point - perhaps it will always be the right ctx without using another IIFE, not 100% sure, might depend on usage.